# Butchering allies?

Tags: rimworld

So, recently my colony came under attack while an allied trading caravan was visiting. With the help of my allies I managed to defeat the raid with no small losses on both sides. Some of my allies died too.

Now my food is running low and I was wondering, will my allies get mad at me if I butcher their dead? My colonists dont really mind, they're all on mental breaks regardless most of the time, but I can deal with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your allies won't mind. Once they're dead you can pretty much do to the bodies what you want. You can even turn their skin into human leather hats and sell those back to your allies.

Comment: That is an excellent idea, now i even have a way of profiting off my allies deaths! Thank you very much.